# Pre installed qemu disk images

Tags: qemu

I am trying to find a qemu disk that has the CentOS 7 installed on it. I can find qcow2 image though. They are same or different? How do I find an image that has the CentOS pre-installed on it

Comment: I think you've already found it. qcow2 is the standard disk image format for qemu.

Comment: `qcow` stands for QEMU Copy On Write. `qcow2` is `qcow` version 2. The image you found is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: I downloaded qcow2 and I am able to convert them to raw, vmdk etc. I generated an ova out of it using raw->vmdk conversion and using my ovf to get a final OVA. Sadly, I am not sure how to get the username and password for it. Anyone knows how to do it?